# Stiching 3D micrographs

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have several scans from [confocal microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_microscopy) and I need them merged. The sample was moved only in one direction without any change in tilt, viewfield, rotation, but there are small differences in the overlapping area. Images are greyscale `1024x1024 px` each.

Right now I'm stitching the data manually, cropping the images and merging them, which is slow and edge is quite visible. I can get better results using Photoshop, but I can process images only not the height data.

My idea is to find overlapping areas, align the images and merge. Now I'm stuck with finding coordinates of common points.

I tried to start with two points set manually and their coordinates stored in

```
        Left  Right
Coords=[0  0 ,X1 Y1;  % common points in 1st image
        X2 Y2,0  0];  % common points in 2nd image
```

Then use surrounding of those points and calculate the difference between the areas for several misalignments in all four directions. Where the minimu is, there should be best match...

```
Img{1}=double(imread(['foo.jpg']));
Img{2}=double(imread(['bar.jpg']));
span=1:21;
ms=round(mean(span));
for ii=span
  for jj=span
    IA=Img{1}(Coords(1,4)-50+ii-ms:Coords(1,4)+50+ii-ms,Coords(1,3)-50+jj-ms:Coords(1,3)+50+jj-ms);
    IB=Img{2}(Coords(2,2)-50+ii-ms:Coords(2,2)+50+ii-ms,Coords(2,1)-50+jj-ms:Coords(2,1)+50+jj-ms);
    Delta(ii,jj)=sum(sum(abs(IA-IB)));
  end
end
```

`Delta` should have minimum near the center, depending on accuracy of the `Coords` estimate, but it looks completely different.

[image: Delta]

Question is, where I'm wrong with my approach and how can I merge the images (semi)automatically?

Comment: Just to make things clear you know that the difference between the images is just some translation between them and you want to find the translation?

Comment: Yes. Next image is taken approximately 900 px to the right and several pixels up or down. The exposure and focus can differ slightly though.

Comment: Have you tried to use normalize correlation to find the translation. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: @AmitayNachmani No, I haven't. Image processing is very far away from my scope. Probably  I'm just reinventing the wheel. I'll try it next week.

Comment: @AmitayNachmani I 've tried the algorithms, but they are quite inaccurate when seeking through whole image, but they will do the job.